How to Scrape Multiple Pages in Parallel Using Ctrl+A and Ctrl+C Without Mixing Up Text?
I'm using Puppeteer to scrape text from multiple pages by navigating to each page, selecting all content using Ctrl+A, copying it with Ctrl+C, and then retrieving the clipboard data. However, I'm encountering issues with text from one page getting mixed up with text from other pages.
const ctrlActrlC = async (page: Page) => {
  await page.keyboard.down("ControlLeft");
  await page.keyboard.press("KeyA");
  await page.keyboard.press("KeyC");
  await page.keyboard.up("ControlLeft");
  // Add a slight delay to allow the clipboard to update
  await sleep(100);
};


const copyTextUsingHtml = (page: Page) =>
  page.evaluate(() => {
    let bodyText = "";
    const extractText = (node) => {
      if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        // If it's a text node, append the text content
        bodyText += `${node.textContent.trim()} `;
      } else if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        const style = window.getComputedStyle(node);
        if (style.display !== "none" && style.visibility !== "hidden") {
          for (const element of node.childNodes) extractText(element);
        }
      }
    };
    // @ts-expect-error defined in browser
    extractText(document.body);
    return bodyText.trim();
  }) as Promise<string>;

const copyAllVisibleText = async (page: Page) => {
  let attempts = 0;
  const maxAttemptes = 32;
  await page.waitForSelector("body", { timeout: 10000 });
  await closePopUp(page);
  await page.focus("body");
  while (attempts < maxAttemptes) {
    for (
      const text of await Promise.all([
        withFocusLock(copyText)(page),
        copyTextUsingHtml(page),
      ])
    ) { 
        if (somePredicateOnText(text)) return text;      }
    }
    await sleep(500);
    attempts++;
  }
  return null;
};

withFocusLock is a browser level mutex which contains bringToFront after locking.

Please share a [mcve] that defines all of these functions and includes the page being manipulated. Consider if there's another approach to achieving your underlying goal than the clipboard (provide full context for the high-level goal). withPageLock is not defined in your code--I assume you mean withFocusLock? Thanks.

Yes, fixed.
Can't share the page being manipulated atm (it's also not a single page).
Whiich functions you want defined?

Basically enough code I can execute and see the problem so I can fix it and post a solution.

I've yet to reproduce it locally myself, so I can't provide that. It happens once in awhile in production.

I understand, but consider a step backward and provide the goal/context so that another approach than the clipboard can be suggested.

@ggorlen What I need is mainly to understand how context and page focus affect using a programmatic keyboard copy paste in headless mode

According to the MDN, the clipboard api will only work if the page is focused. You would also have to provide the app with proper permissions.

The specification requires that a user has recently interacted with the page in order to read from the clipboard (transient user activation is required).

Here is a minimal working code here,
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";
import { setTimeout } from "node:timers/promises";

async function scrapeWithClipboard(url: string) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
  });

  const context = await browser.defaultBrowserContext();

  await context.overridePermissions(url, ['clipboard-read', 'clipboard-write', 'clipboard-sanitized-write']);

  const page = await context.newPage();

  await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "networkidle0" });

  // Select all text (Ctrl+A)
  await page.keyboard.down("Control");
  await page.keyboard.press("KeyA");
  await page.keyboard.up("Control");

  // Copy selected text (Ctrl+C)
  await page.keyboard.down("Control");
  await page.keyboard.press("KeyC");
  await page.keyboard.up("Control");

  await setTimeout(500);

  // The clipboard api does not allow you to copy, unless the tab is focused.
  await page.bringToFront();
  const clipboardText = await page.evaluate(() => {
    // Copy the selected content to the clipboard
    document.execCommand("copy");
    // Obtain the content of the clipboard as a string
    return navigator.clipboard.readText();
  });

  await browser.close();
  return clipboardText;
}

scrapeWithClipboard("https://example.com").then(console.log);

The reason the clipboard content can get mixed up is if you have multiple tabs open, or multiple pages accessing the clipboard at same time. So you should ensure only one page is active at once until the whole copy-paste process is done.

withFocusLock contains bringToFront + a browser level mutex (sorry I thought the name implies it)
